# Mobile sentient plant-like species

Tags: science-based, creature-design, science-fiction, flora

I know similar questions are asked a lot and it's okay if you'll just send me to where my question is already answered, but i couldn't find clear answer if exactly what i need is possible.

So. I need this plant-race to be created artificially (by very distant future humans if it's matters) They created them as companions to people with whom they want to populate a new planet.

I need them to fit the requirements:

1. They can move around (Although if they could sometimes dig up roots and then pull them out and move on, that would be cool too?)
2. They are intelligent at the human level (They can speak, feel, have their own consciousness, etc.)
3. They produce oxygen through photosynthesis, although **they obtain energy through food consumption**
4. Also I'm not sure about if it can/should always grow and be able to grow back a body part?

Is creature suitable for all requests above possible?

Comment: Seems like you're asking us to help you brainstorm a cool critter for your world. We're not a brainstorming site. If you have a specific problem you're looking for help solving with your plantfolk you can ask about that. However questions like this where the answer is entirely based on the creativity and discretion of the worldbuilder aren't permitted on this site.

Comment: @sphennings I'm just asking if what i described is possible, all "maybes" are my guesses of solving the problem, but not here to be answered. Basically i'm asking if walking sapient plant is possible if it gains energy through nutrition (because i've serarched through other questions and could not find information about mobile, not immobile plant species)

Comment: What you are asking about is an animal which can also photosynthesize. Yes, it is possible. Humans are an example. A human carrying a potted flower obviously satisfies the requirements; but this is *small scale*. We are mobile, sentient, intelligent, can talk, have consciousness etc., and we also can sow seeds of wheat and maize and tomatoes and oaks, which we tend to, take care of, and which grow to do the photosynthesis. Yes, the photosynthesizing bits are not part of our bodies; but this is an *advantage*, because we can grow them so very very much larger than our bodies.

Comment: Triffids!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy5MDAiBiqo  Keep the salt water away. (Though that was only in the movie.)

Comment: The truth though is that the Blight uplifted them as a way of planting (pun intended) a fifth column throughout the Beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can imagine a super-advanced society engineering a plant with these capabilities, although it might be more of an animal hybrid than a plant. The hard parts would be movement and humanlike intelligence. For movement, it would probably walk, eat, and store energy just like an animal, except it would be able to totally shut itself down and revert to a plantlike state for lower energy consumption, which is where the plant part comes in. I don't imagine photosynthesis would make a dent in the energy required for moving greater distances.

As for intelligence and communication, I don't think that a human brain is necessary - you might be able to get away with using a bioengineered implementation of specifically engineered neural networks, say a chatbot module, feelings module, etc.

The communication side of this already kind of exists in a digital form and would probably only require neurons numbering in the hundreds, which I think is perfectly reasonable for a plant to have, and communication with them would be done through an electrode-computer interface, shifting the energy requirements of vocalization from the plant to the computer. This would allow the important part - the companionship - to be on at all times, as long as you have batteries for your communicator. Higher functioning might function similarly but be reserved for the animal part.

We can already connect electrodes to plants to detect their communication, this would just be an advanced form of it.

Basically, I imagine they would be more like biological robots engineered and trained purposefully for human interaction. You can feed them and get them to walk and talk with you, and once you're at home, put them in a pot and they'll sit on your desk under a light, wirelessly charging, and pay you company.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe but they probably wouldn't be what you are thinking of.

For one thing, you posit human like intelligence.  The trouble with that is that our brain is one of the biggest energy consumers in our body.  You could say that all of our body is designed to feed our brain.

A plant that used photosynthesis would have to be **huge** to get enough energy to support that.  Either that or the thinking would have to be slow enough that communication with humans would be difficult.

There are trees that currently travel.  They grow roots in the direction they need to go (probably toward water and away from shade but I don't know enough about them to say).  Needless to say, this movement is very slow.  You would measure it using a calendar, not a watch.

So, the main thing the plant would need is a way to get enough energy fast enough to do what you want.  Or it can be so big and slow that it could be living on Earth now and we just haven't recognized it yet.

Answer (score 3):

In John Scalzi's novel Old Man's War, humanity makes artificial human-like bodies to be used as super-soldiers. Sometimes people get their minds transferred to these bodies, but sometimes there isn't a mind available so these bodies develop one of their own. Due to this I count them as an artificial creature developed by humanity.

Besides being faster, stronger than humans etc., they also have chlorophyll in their skins, making them green. In the novel this allows them to generate a little bit of oxygen, thus being able to hold their breath longer.

In reality they would be able to hold their breaths not a millisecond longer than usual with that, and the author could have considered cetacean myoglobin instead. It just happens that Scalzi is an awesome writer rather than a boring nerd. Old Man's War works because of Suspension of Disbelief and The Rule Of Cool.

So do what you want. It's your skills as a writer and/or storyteller that are important when telling a story or building a world. Unless you are into hard-scifi, in which case [XKCD will totally murder your idea](https://what-if.xkcd.com/17/).

Comment: I need them to replace plants for other people, but they themselves live off the same nutrition (eating same diet with people), it's impossible anyway? In any case, thanks a lot for your answer 

Comment: @AnimagKrasver it is possible, it is just that photosynthesys is impractible for animals larger than a few milimeters. Some sea slugs do it by breaking down algae and stealing their chloroplasts, but even for them photosynthesis is a small part of their caloric intake.

Answer (score 0):

**These things were already on the planet.**

Doing the things you want them to do!  Getting sun.  Eating some treats.  Moving around.  Maybe some other things we can learn about later in the story...

They are biologically much like Earth life via [panspermia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panspermia). The artificial part is mostly breeding.  The humans bred smarter ones that were better companions, just like humans have been doing with wild creatures for millenia.

There is also a little bit of /cross a human being and a plant/ - a touch of GMO and human genes governing neural development.  That trick was developed for horses originally.  The [uplifted](https://www.yalescientific.org/2015/05/science-or-science-fiction-uplifting-animals/) horses turned out really great and they are everywhere with humans now.  That is why the humans did it again with the plant companions.

The wild predecessors of the plant companions are still on the planet.  They are not radically different from your plant companion beings.  The two types can communicate, and reproduce.  The product of such a union might be unlike either parent.